# Salesforce Push Notification in Ionic 3

Tags: cordova, push-notification, salesforce, ionic3

Is is possible to implement **Salesforce Push Notification** with **Ionic 3**?Please give me working example code.

We have searched over many sites, but they all are working on salesforce **force-hybrid/native** but none of it tell about any way to work with **ionic framework**. It was working on the **ionic 1**... But it was deprecated now.

So, anybody have any workaround so that we can merge both workings.

This request was specially for push notifications, because for push notification, salesforce required to add Google project id in bootconfig.json, but this was not created when we create project with ionic framework.

So, just need any workaround for this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pushImplGuide.meta/pushImplGuide/pns_client_app_hybrid.htm

Comment: Hi Suraj, Thank you for your reply but we are not talking about force-hybrid app we are talking about ionic.